# How to manually place labels on Y-Axis without placing space

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two data points graph on a single figure, and i had done this task, i am using Python along with Matplotlib for this task.
But the problem comes when i want to add text to ylabel, adding text is simple but i want to add text adjacent to my graphs and that too without using spaces.
Currently i am using spaces, but this will create problem when figures are scaled down to different sizes, i hope there could another better way of doing this.
I break down my problem to simple scenario, the code for that is as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

# Sampling Frequency
SampleFreq = 500.0
time_axis = np.arange(0, 1.0, 1/SampleFreq)

sin_sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * time_axis) + 2.0
cos_sig = np.cos(2 * np.pi * 10 * time_axis)

plt.plot(time_axis, sin_sig ,color='#000080', linewidth=1.0)
plt.plot(time_axis, cos_sig ,'r', linewidth=1.0)
plt.xlim(0, 1.0)
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Time in ms', fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Cos Signal                    \
                    Sine Signal',fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the image, sine and cos signals are written on the ylabel, but they are adjusted by using space.

[image: Output Image]

I hope someone can help in finding the correct solution for this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two subplots, one for each curve but with a different ylabel.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)


# Sampling Frequency
SampleFreq = 500.0
time_axis = np.arange(0, 1.0, 1/SampleFreq)

sin_sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * time_axis)
cos_sig = np.cos(2 * np.pi * 10 * time_axis)

ax2.plot(time_axis, sin_sig ,color='#000080', linewidth=1.0)
ax.plot(time_axis, cos_sig ,'r', linewidth=1.0)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 1.0)
for a in [ax,ax2]:
    a.set_yticks([-1,1])
    a.set_yticklabels(["off", "on"])
    a.grid(True, axis='x',)


ax2.set_xlabel('Time in ms', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel("Sine Signal",fontweight='bold')
ax2.set_ylabel("Cos Signal",fontweight='bold')

ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day, thanks alot.
One more question i want to ask, is it also possible to put yticks with some some text, for example on ax axis -1 as off and +1 as on